# What is the value of an empty cell in a SQLite DB in iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite

Given a SQLite database with records consisting of multiple text columns, what is the value of an empty cell (i.e., a cell that has never been updated)? Would it be nil, 0, or possibly empty string?

For example, consider the following table where A, B, and C are text columns:

```
id A B C
_  _ _ _
1  d e f
2  g h
3  i
```

What would be the value of cells 2C, 3B, and 3C?

If I were to update this table one record at a time, using the following query

```
update table set A=? B=? C=? where id=?
```

What would be the bind value of '?' when updating a record with an empty cell? I'm working with iOS if that matters.

Since only some cells are empty, the other option would be to update the table one cell at a time instead of one record at a time. That feels inefficient, however.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. The database value is `NULL`. How that `NULL` gets converted to a specific value in your code depends on your code and the data type. Provide more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the SQLite documentation[1], a new value is either the default value defined when the table was created/last modified or `NULL`, which is different than `nil` in iOS.

Assuming you have control of the database in question, you can define a default value in that table that will suit your needs. If that is not the case, your code will need to test the value to make sure it is handled appropriately.

[1] https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html